# mapping multiword expressions to be shown in django

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to create annotated text for showing in Django. To do that I'm mapping existing list of multiword expressions to be tagged to the text and get out something like this, where first two elements are starting and ending points and third is a dictionary with some information about the phrase :

```
[[2,5,{phrase: 'contains important information', foo: 'bar'}],
 [...]]
```

What is the most reasonable (and also fastest) way to change the structure into something like this:

```
[['This'],
 ['list'],
 ['contains important information',{foo:'bar'}],
 [...]]
```

Or perhaps I'm approaching from the wrong direction at all?

Comment: I don't see where the ´This´ and ´List´ in the target came from in the source, and I don't see where the ´2´ and ´5´ in the source ended up in the target. It's a bit confusing. Does your example represent a clean mapping from the source data structure to the target data structure?

Comment: Sorry if confusing, trying to clarify: The example sentence is "This list contains important information" and the mapper takes it in as a list: ['This','list','contains','important','information'] and outputs mapped phrases with indexes. What I need is a way to create a multidimensional list from original sentence and mapping results which contains original words (those that didn't match to any phrases) and annotated phrases. Hope this helps.